# Exception “String reference not set to an instance of a String” in php soap client

Tags: php, web-services, api, exception, soap

I'm trying to write a soap client for the service at:
http://link-products.chiangcn.com/APIService.asmx
http://link-products.chiangcn.com/APIService.asmx?WSDL

I queried the types (_getTypes) that the service offers . Below is the type structure for the 'GetAuthorizedCategories' operation I'm trying to perform:

```
Types:
struct GetAuthorizedCategories {
    string Request;
}
```

Below is my php code that tries to use the web service's 'GetAuthorizedCategories' operation:

```
<?php
$soap = new SoapClient('http://link-products.chiangcn.com/APIService.asmx?WSDL');
$arg = new stdClass;
$arg -> ClientId = 'ccd839ad-aef4-4748-a1c5-5235ef24f8ad';
$arg -> AccessToken = "155a0d0c2fea4e8a8c6da4bf5366241d";
$arguments = array('Request' => $arg);
$obj = $soap -> __soapCall('GetAuthorizedCategories', $arguments);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($obj);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This is Exception I'm getting from the webservice.

```
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'GetAuthorizedCategoriesResult' => string '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Code>0</Code>
  <Message>System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
   at PushData.Service.Utility.DeserializeXML[T](String xml)
   at PushData.Service.APIService.GetAuthorizedCategories(String Request)</Message>
</Errors>' (length=459)
```

This is the first SOAP client I'm writing. Any help in fixing this will be useful.

PS: This is the document of webservice
[image: document]

Answer (score 0):

Build a normal array instead of using the stdClass instance. See if that works.

**EDIT**

If you havent tried. build XML and use that as $arg.

you can see here for extra info 
http://link-products.chiangcn.com/APIService.asmx?op=GetAuthorizedCategories

Comment: could you do a var_dump($arg); and then post it here.

Comment: Thanks for your patient.                                                              `array (size=1)
  'Request' => 
    array (size=2)
      'ClientId' => string 'ccd839ad-aef4-4748-a1c5-5235ef24f8ad' (length=36)
      'AccessToken' => string '155a0d0c2fea4e8a8c6da4bf5366241d' (length=32)
`